# Is it dangerous to eat bananas and eggs together?

Tags: nutrition, food-poisoning

I read that the combination of bananas and eggs is poisonous. I searched on the internet and found out that certain food (fruits and eggs, fruits and milk) shouldn't be eaten together but I couldn't understand why.
Is this true? and what happens to my body if I eat them together?

Comment: That would explain why my guests keep dying. It's the banana-egg soup I have been serving.

Comment: Oh, RIP poor guests! :(

Comment: Maybe but what about milkshake we mix the milk with banana but i have seen many people which mix eggs in milkshake as well.... So it's 99.99% wrong

Answer (score 7):

Utter nonsense. Many common recipes combine bananas and eggs. People eat bananas with eggs all the time without harm. I've had some of these myself and they're tasty.

[Banana pancakes](http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-2-ingredient-banana-pancakes-cooking-lessons-from-the-kitchn-218658)

[Banana bread](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/20144/banana-banana-bread/)

[Fruity egg muffins](http://www.feedingfinn.com/fruity-egg-muffins-3-ingredients/)

[Banana Licuado](http://www.safeeggs.com/recipes/banana-licuado-recipe)

Comment: I agree. Where could this myth have surfaced?

Comment: This is all planned against the ones who care about health :0

Answer (score 5):

> I read that the combination of bananas and eggs is poisonous.

Can you please give the exact links? Google does [auto-suggest](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=banana%20and%20eggs%20poison) a link but as Carey has also mentioned, it doesn't make any sense.

It is highly unlikely that a fruit (banana which is rich in Potassium, Vitamins C & B6, Fibre and fats) and egg( rich in Fats, protein, and cholesterol) would mix up together to form anything toxic.
Instead, they are generally mixed together, to make different recipes like [pancake](http://www.huffingtonpost.in/entry/2-ingredient-banana-pancake-recipe_us_565c4682e4b08e945feb9a3c). Please try looking [at right places to read](https://scholar.google.co.in/scholar?hl=en&q=egg%2Bbanana&btnG=), and yes, do NOT always believe in what you read online!

Comment: Yeah you are right, I know it sounds stupid, that's what I thought when I read it the first time but then I found it on websites like:
   http://www.urdumania.net/foods-you-should-not-eat-together/
and this one:
http://learningdays.tumblr.com/post/24606562484/toxic-food-combinations
and this is what made me curious to find out the truth.
Thank you!

Comment: @LamiaKouba That tumblr link is ridiculous. According to that, almost every food is toxic when mixed with anything else. If you followed their advice virtually every dish in every culture would be "toxic".

Comment: I second @CareyGregory. Also, i can not recall anything like that written in Ayurveda. Yes, some mixtures are not good for health, but certainly not these two.